# Where's the key to Stoneridge Watch? ('Old Friends' quest)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-falskaar

[I need a key to enter Stoneridge Watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt5ue.jpg) for the ['Old Friends' quest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pwLT.jpg). I've killed every bandit outside and searched them but haven't been able to find the key.

Does anyone know where it is?

Comment: To the downvoter(s): Could you please consider commenting on why you downvoted this question? This is so I (and others) would know what was wrong with it, and so I could address that concern or edit the question to improve it. When downvotes are left without comments and the reasons for doing so are unclear, you'll often see users (like myself) wanting to know the reason why.

Comment: I had to enter through the unlocked trapdoor on the floor in one of the towers

Comment: Downvoting is stupidity IMHO because it's an action that cost voters reputation. Well, at least is how it works in othr StackEchange sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is inside Stoneridge Watch. To get inside you need to enter through a trapdoor that is in the back left tower as you enter the courtyard.